# Declaring and Initializing 2D array of unknown size in C

Tags: c, arrays

I plan to create an 2D array of a pointer derived from `typedef struct`

Let's say the `typedef struct` is named "Items" and contains mixed variables of strings and integers.

I will declare two `int`variables namely `typenum` and `typetotal`. These two integers will start off from Zero and adds up when the input data matches with certain function.

In the array,`Items *type[][]`, basically `type[][]` is `Items *type[typenum][typetotal]` but I cannot do this since I will declare `typenum` and `typetotal` as zero at the declaration part.

I tried initializing the array through `Items *type[][] = {{0},{0}}` but this generates error.

Any advice? Some told me to use malloc() on this, but I simply do not know how.

*Using Tiny C on Windows

Comment: Don't listen to the answers posted here but instead check out [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dynamic memory allocation.

```
Items **type;
type = malloc(sizeof (Items *) * typenum);

for (int i = 0; i < typenum; i++)
    type[i] = malloc(sizeof Items) * typetotal);
```

You need to manually free the allocated memory after using the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < typenum; i++)
    free(types[i]);

free(types);
```

Here is a tutorial on it: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: @Rafi Kamal Will this code work if I want to initialize single bracket array?

Comment: @BeginnerC You mean 1D array? It will work with some modification. Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

Comment: @RafiKamal Can't I put the `free(types[i];` after `type[i] = malloc(sizeof Items) * typetotal);`?

Comment: `malloc` is used for allocating memory to a pointer. `free` is for freeing the allocated memory when your program no longer needs it. You will call `free` only after you are done with the array. Please check the two tutorials I've given, you'll find detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

If `typenum` and `typetotal` increase as your program runs be sure to use `realloc`, which will reallocate more memory and keep the contents. You'll need to allocate the first dimension of the array like this:

```
myArray = realloc(myArray, sizeof(Items*) * typenum);
```

and then allocate the second dimension for each of the first:

```
for(...)
    myArray[i] = realloc(myArray[i], sizeof(Items) * typetotal);
```

Comment: Will I use `realloc` everytime when the `typenum` and `typetotal` increases?

Comment: That's right. Beware of running out of memory, in which it'll return NULL but leave the *old* memory allocated, not freed, likely memory leak!!

Comment: Just so that it is clear to me, I shall put `type[i] = malloc(sizeof Items) * typetotal)` first then below it, I will put your suggested code, `type[i] = realloc(type[i],sizeof(Items) * typetotal);` Then after that, I will add `free(type[i]);` then I will end the bracket for the `for(...)` and put `free(types);`?

Comment: no, use realloc instead. When you pass NULL into the realloc call it'll act the same as malloc.